# How to access USB devices in WSL in Windows?

Tags: usb, wsl2

I am using WSL2 in Windows 11, I wanted to access my USB thermal printer from command line for testing purposes. I was able to access my printer in Linux in the path `/dev/usb/lp1` (where lp1 stand for line printer 1). Any idea?

Comment: This was just asked yesterday -- See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/q/1681809/1210833) for details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access/mount a Windows USB device in WSL](https://superuser.com/questions/1681809/how-to-access-mount-a-windows-usb-device-in-wsl)